# Why is wtforms SelectMultipleField returning no selected values?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to use the flask (2.1.3) wtforms (3.0.1) SelectMultipleField() type.  It renders just fine.  I can select multiple values but none of them are in the form result after submission.

My form class looks like:

```
class ClassesForm(FlaskForm):
    my_choices = [
        ('Kindergarten', 'Kindergarten'),
        ('1st', '1st'),
        ('2nd', '2nd'),
        ('3rd', '3rd'),
        ('4th', '4th'),
        ('5th', '5th'),
        ('6th', '6th'),
        ('7th', '7th'),
        ('8th', '8th'),
        ('9th', '9th'),
        ('10th', '10th'),
        ('11th', '11th'),
        ('12th', '12th'),
        ('Other', 'Other'),
    ]

    name = StringField(
        'Class name (Science I, Bio, etc.)',
        render_kw={
            'placeholder': 'Class name  (Science I, Bio, etc.)',
            'aria-label': 'Class name',
        },
        validators=[
            validators.DataRequired(),
            validators.Length(min=1, max=128)
        ]
    )

    grades = SelectMultipleField(
        'Grades Taught',
        choices=my_choices,
        render_kw={
            'size': '6',
            'aria-label': 'Grades Taught',
        },
        validators=[
            validators.DataRequired(),
        ]
    )

    students = IntegerField(
        'Number of students',
        render_kw={
            'placeholder': 'Number of students',
            'aria-label': 'Number of students',
        },
        validators=[
            validators.DataRequired()
        ]
    )
    
    submit = SubmitField('Save')
```

The rendered html for the form field looks like:

```
<label for="grades">Grades Taught</label>
<select id="grades" class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" aria-label="Grades Taught" multiple="">
    <option value="Kindergarten">Kindergarten</option>
    <option value="1st">1st</option>
    <option value="2nd">2nd</option>
    <option value="3rd">3rd</option>
    <option value="4th">4th</option>
    <option value="5th">5th</option>
    <option value="6th">6th</option>
    <option value="7th">7th</option>
    <option value="8th">8th</option>
    <option value="9th">9th</option>
    <option value="10th">10th</option>
    <option value="11th">11th</option>
    <option value="12th">12th</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

I am using a view class to handle the results. The "post" method looks like:

```
class ClassesAPI(MethodView):
    decorators = [login_required]
    
    @staticmethod
    def post():
        try:
            my_session = db()

            form = ClassesForm(request.form, obj=current_user)

            if form.validate():
                # Copy form fields to user_profile fields
                my_class = Classes()
                form.populate_obj(my_class)

                current_user.schools['classes'].append(my_class)

                # Save user_profile
                my_session.commit()

                return Response(status=HTTPStatus.OK)
            else:
                return make_response({
                    'validation_errors': form.errors
                })
        except Exception as e:
            return Response(repr(e), status=HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
```

The validation error reported is that the "grades" field has no values.

I have seen SO posts that suggest getting the "grades" list by these methods:

```
grades = request.form.getlist('grades')
--or--
grades = request.form.grades.data
```

The second one does not work as I am told that `form` has no member `grades`.  The first first just returns and empty list.

I can put a breakpoint on the `if` statement and examine the `form` variable and the `request.form` structures and there are no values in the `grades` portion of the form data.

Comment: Have you tried `request.form.get('grades')`?

Comment: At this point, I can't recall if I have done that but I will asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in the flask `form_macros` included template.  I was generating a `select` but I forgot to add a `name="..."` attribute to the select widget.